# Can I absolutely rely on CountRoots and RootIntervals?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I have some polynomials of high degree with coefficients of the form `a + b Sqrt[5]` where `a`, `b` are integers (or at least rationals).

I want to *rigorously* determine when they have all real roots - that means symbolically, and not numerically.

It seems to me that `CountRoots` and `RootIntervals` do actually work exactly (presumably via Sturm sequences or similar) when the polynomials have integer coefficients, but do they work correctly and exactly for ANY symbolically defined coefficients?

Comment: No reports of errors on this site.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Are the implementations in Mathematica known to be implementations of exact algorithms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `CountRoots` and `RootIntervals` use exact algorithms. For non-polynomial functions `CountRoots` may use numeric integration, but if it does it issues a warning message.

```
In[1]:= CountRoots[1 - x + Gamma[x], {x, 2 - I, 4 + I}]                         

CountRoots::nint: Warning: Numeric integration was used to count roots.

Out[1]= 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I accepted this answer, but the colour scheme is different from the other StackExchange sites I use, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @GordonRoyle It is marked as "accepted".

Comment: "exact algorithms" - it's still Collins-Krandick, correct? Or has it been replaced by something newer? (I'm no longer current with these things, I'm afraid.)